# I am a Spanish speaker, and I used this sentence in a conversation:

Tags: word-choice

“We always use that one”
Because 8 times out of 10 we have.

My meaning is that most of the times we use that, so I went with the word “always”.

The person that I was speaking with told me it was not correct, because it was not always because always means all the time. I was not using the exact meaning of always, but this person couldn’t understand my explanation.

So which one is correct?

“We always use that”
“Most of the time we use that”

Comment: Formally it is not correct, but many native speakers would say that in informal speech as referring to always.  If you are in a debate, no don't use always, but in general informal speech, that is fine.

Comment: I would qualify it: *We **almost** always use that one.*

Answer (score 7):

This is entirely dependent on context.

This use of *always* is an exaggeration.  Exaggeration is appropriate in certain contexts and inappropriate in other contexts.

For example, in the following dialogue, exageration is not appropriate:

> Person A: We're conducting an official audit of such-and-such. Please describe your process for doing such-and-such.
>   Person B: Whenever we do such-and-such, we always check that the value is within the acceptable range.

On the other hand, in the following case, exaggeration is fine:

> Person A: Do you like to go to the movies?
>   Person B: I sure do! I always go to see the big new releases.